# Show that vectors $\mathbf{u} = \cos(x)$, $\mathbf{v} = \sin(x)$, $\mathbf{w} = 2$ are linearly independent. Why is this approach correct?

Tags: linear-algebra

The task is

> Let V be the vector space of continuous functions defined on the real line.
>
> Let $\mathbf{u} = \cos(x)$, $\mathbf{v} = \sin(x)$, $\mathbf{w} = 2$
>
> Show that vectors $\bf u,v ,w$ are independent.

Author's solution is:

We have linear combination

$$\tag{*}k_{1} \cos(x) + k_{2}\sin(x) + 2k_{3} $$

We need three equations, so we substitute three different values of x into (∗). We choose values that help to simplify the equations.

$$\tag{1}k_{1} \cos(0) + k_{2}\sin(0) + 2k_{3} =k_{1} + 2k_{3}$$
$$\tag{2}k_{1} \cos(\pi) + k_{2}\sin(\pi) + 2k_{3} = -k_{1} + 2k_{3}$$
$$\tag{3}k_{1} \cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) + k_{2}\sin(\frac{\pi}{2}) + 2k_{3} = k_{2} + 2k_{3} $$

Then he writes three equations above into the augmented matrix form and solves it. And the result is:

$$k_{1} = k_{2} = k_{3} = 0$$

---

What I don't understand there, does this approach really solve the problem? If I get the statement of the problem correctly, we need to show that vectors $\bf u,v,w$ are independent **for all** $x$. Yet he's just shown that vectors will be independent provided that $x =0,\pi,\frac{\pi}{2}$. What am I missing?

Comment: It's actually the other way around. If they're linearly dependent, they must be so for all $x$. In other words, if you can find at least one $x$ where they're not linearly dependent, then they can never be linearly dependent as functions.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi "If they're linearly dependent, they must be so for all ". Could you explain why, please?

Comment: $\mathbf u$ is the _function_ $\cos$. So for $\mathbf{u,v,w}$ to be dependent, we would need $k_1,k_2,k_3$ such that $k_1\cos x + k_2\sin x + 2k_3$ is zero _as an element of the vector space of functions_; i.e. it is zero for all $x$.

Comment: For linear dependence, the constants must be "uniform". In mathematics, especially real analysis, uniform for a function means that it doesn't depend on where it happens. So let's say for some $x$ there is some choice of constants that gets the functions to cancel out. But let's say at a different $x$ a different set of constants that conflict with the previous set make the the functions cancel. These aren't "uniform" constants because they depend on $x$. But the operation of multiplying a function by a constant is a "uniform" act, that is to say it applies to all $x$ equally.

Comment: Intuitively, it's like a game of whack-a-mole. If you choose constants to cancel the functions out at one location, that may cause the functions to not cancel out somewhere else, if they were linearly independent.

Comment: @Ninad Munshi, to make sure that I'm getting this, let's consider an example. We have functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that, say, $11\cdot f(2) + 8\cdot g(2) = 69$. Does it imply that for all $x$, $11\cdot f(x) + 8 \cdot g(x) = 69$ will hold?

Comment: If it did, that would make f and g linearly dependent. But with what you have written just now, you cannot make the assumption go that way.

Comment: Nelver, here is an example the other way: the functions $(x+1)^2,x^2,$ and $2x+1$ are _not_ independent, because $(x+1)^2-x^2-(2x+1)=0$ for all $x$.

Comment: What is important to understand is that in the vector space of continuous functions, the zero element is the _function_ $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $f(x)=0$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 3):

The equation holds for all $x$ and we are free to make any choices for $x$. Your aim is to somehow prove that the coefficients are $0$. Note that **for all** is in the hypothesis part and not the conclusion part of the question.